# Mongodb find and insert

Tags: mongodb

I would like to:

1) find documents

2) each of the found documents include an array, I would like to insert a new array element into the array. If the array element already exists, do nothing (do not insert a new element into the array).

I've played with aggregation however I can't seem to find an insert function?

Data:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("560c24b853b558856ef193a4"),
    "name" : "ирина",
    "pic" : "",
    "language" : ObjectId("560c24b853b558856ef193a2"),
    "cell" : 1,
    "local" : {
        "email" : "ирина@mail.com",
        "password" : "12345"
    },
    "sessions" : [ // <--- this is the array I would like to insert a new element into
        {
            "id" : ObjectId("560c24b853b558856ef193a5")
        }
    ]
}
```

Insert:

```
        yield new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            users.col.aggregate([
                    {
                        $match: {
                            'cell': socket.cell
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        // <--- insert here?
                    }
                ],
                function (err, res) {
                    if (err === null)
                        resolve(res);
                    reject(err);
                });
        });
```

Update.

Tried the following also not willing to insert :/

```
yield new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    var bulk = users.col.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
bulk.find({
        cell: 1
    }).update({
        $addToSet: {
            sessions: {
                id: 'test'
            }
        }
    });
    bulk.execute(function (err, res) {
        console.log(res);
        resolve(res);
    });
});
```

Comment: a simple [`update`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/) will work here

Comment: @user3100115 so like `$match` but `$update`?

Comment: you really don't need aggregation or the bulk operation here this is very simple.

Comment: @user3100115 I've been reading what you linked but have no idea how that could accomplish it, maybe if you were to give an example I would understand it more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using co-monk:

```
yield users.update({
    cell: 1
}, {
    $addToSet: {
        sessions: {
            id: 'test'
        }
    }
}, {
    multi: true
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**As stated by user3100115** you should use update as follows:

```
db.collection.update({cell:1},{$addToSet:{sessions:{id: 'test'}}},{multi:true})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bulk operations, particularly [`Bulk.find`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk.find/#Bulk.find) and update. As for adding unique values, you can use [`$addToSet`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/)

```
var bulk = db.items.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
bulk.find({cell: socket.cell}).update({$addToSet: {sessions: id}});
```

Comment: Hello, I tried to implement your type of answer however still not working. I've updated the question with code.